# I have a table which has multiple entries and I want to delete on or more of them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has multiple entries using a common date, and I want to delete on or more of them. The deletion will be based on the values in a second table. Here is an example.

Table 1:

```
Row Customer   Task   Frequency   Date mm/dd/yy
1   A          X      1           07/01/19
2   A          X      1           08/01/19
3   A          X      1           09/01/19
4   A          Y      3           09/01/19
5   A          X      1           10/01/19
6   A          W      1           10/01/19
7   A          X      1           11/01/19
8   A          X      1           12/01/19
9   A          Y      3           12/01/19
10  A          Z      12          12/01/19
```

This influencing data is from Table 2, linked by Task:

```
Task   Group   Frequency   Priority
X      A       1           1
Y      A       3           2
Z      A       12          3
W      B       10          1
```

The task is to delete the rows in Table 1, where all use the same customer, are on the same date, are in the same group on Table 2 and have the lower priority in Table 2. So un the above example the following rows in Table 1 would be deleted:

3   it belongs to the same group, is on the same date as row 4, but has a lower priority

8 & 9   They belong to the same group and are on the same date as row 12, but have a lower priority

Row 6 Would NOT be deleted as it shares the same date etc., but belongs to a different group.

Table 1 would now look like this (row numbers are purely to help understand the issue):

```
Row Customer   Task    Frequency   Date mm/dd/yy
1   A          X       1           07/01/19
2   A          X       1           08/01/19
3   A          Y       3           09/01/19
4   A          X       1           10/01/19
5   A          W       1           10/01/19
6   A          X       1           11/01/19
7   A          Z       12          12/01/19
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below script(please test it because I don't have access to any SQL server right now for validating any syntax error) -

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        RowIndexing = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Customer, T1.Date, T2.Group ORDER BY T2.Priority DESC)),
        T1.Row
    FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.Task = T1.Task
)
--DELETE T1
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Row = T1.Row
WHERE CTE.RowIndexing > 1
```

Adding new solution below (assuming there are no `Row` column exists in tables)-

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        RowIndexing = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Customer, T1.Date, T2.Group ORDER BY T2.Priority DESC)),
        T1.Customer,
        T1.Task,
        T1.Frequency,
        T1.Date
    FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.Task = T1.Task
)
--DELETE T1
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Customer = T1.Customer AND CTE.Task = T1.Task AND CTE.Frequency = T1.Frequency AND T1.Date = CTE.Date
WHERE CTE.RowIndexing > 1
```

Above solution will return rows which will be deleted if you uncomment `delete` line and comment-out `select` line beneath it.

Comment: Hi and thanks SQLCoder, I have tried that, but the query does not recognise 'Row'.

Comment: ;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        RowIndexing = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.equipid, T1.ContractId, T1.pmDate, T2.calltypeid ORDER BY T2.pmlevel DESC)),
        T1.Row
    FROM smconpmtask T1
 inner join smpmheader T2 on
 T2.Pmtype = T1.pmcode
 
)
--DELETE T1
SELECT T1.*
FROM smconpmtask T1
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Row = T1.Row
WHERE CTE.RowIndexing > 1

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'Row'.

Comment: I'm assuming there is column with name `Row` in `Table1`. I will add new query in my answer now(assuming there is no Row column in tables).

Comment: The CTE returns all row indexes = 1 for some reason so there is no value greater than 1. Also the Delete is unable to include the T2.Priority. The delete should be, at its most basic 'delete where T1.Task =T2.Task and the rows have the same T1.Date and T2.group value, but leave the highest value of T2.Priority.    I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @KevinF - Second query returning exact three records which have to be deleted. I try this on Fiddle but delete don't work over there. Sorry.

Comment: don't worry, but thanks for your help. The problem seems to be deleting records from T1 based upon records in T2.